# Photodiode dark current

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I've biased a photodiode in reverse and measured dark current on multiple temperatures. With the help of Arrhenius plot, I've extracted an activation energy which ended up being half of the bandgap energy. I suspect that (neglecting the injection of carrier from the contact) I have a trap assisted current.

My question is, could you help me correlate the dark current with the traps?

I know the dark current in reverse is proportional to the intrinsic carrier concentration which in turn is proportional to the exp(-Eg/kT). However, I don't know how to correlate traps with this.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer. This relation is explained through the Shockly-Read-Hall model. The reverse current in a photodiode is mainly due to the generation effect which is proportional to the trap energy and bandgap energy. This is described by the SRH model.

If someone is interested in a longer and more detailed answer, he/she can find it in a publication:

Kublitski, Jonas & Hofacker, Andreas & Boroujeni, Bahman & Benduhn, Johannes & Nikolis, Vasileios & Kaiser, Christina & Spoltore, Donato & Kleemann, Hans & Fischer, Axel & Ellinger, Frank & Vandewal, Koen & Leo, Karl. (2021). Reverse dark current in organic photodetectors and the major role of traps as source of noise. Nature Communications. 12. 551. 10.1038/s41467-020-20856-z.

Comment: Very glad that you found the answer - and that you wrote it down for the rest of us.